# How to plot Time series without breaks caused by missing dates?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question has been asked multiple times but I cannot find any that fit my needs.
My goal is to plot timeseries for one month over multiple years. The following JAN dataframe is created by sub-setting from data frame containing daily rainfall for the entire year.

```
> head(JAN)
         DATE         RCM GPM TRI
1: 2000-01-01 0.012182957  NA  NA
2: 2000-01-02 0.001769934  NA  NA
3: 2000-01-03 0.007916438  NA  NA
4: 2000-01-04 0.008227825  NA  NA
5: 2000-01-05 0.005192382  NA  NA
6: 2000-01-06 0.065458169  NA  NA
```

The dataframe is for the month of January containing daily records over 20 years.
I got the following plot.

```
    dfmelt<-melt(JAN,id.vars="DATE")
ggplot(dfmelt,aes(x=DATE,y=value,
                  col=variable,group = lubridate::year(DATE)))+
  labs(title='JANUARY')+
  geom_line()
```

[image: time series plot]

I'm assuming it's because my data consists only January months and while plotting breaks are there for February to December.
I want to avoid this to see the trend of precipitation over the years for the month january.
introducing breaks give the following

```
breaks <- unique(as.Date(cut(dfmelt$DATE, "month")))
ba2 <- transform(dfmelt, year = as.integer(format(DATE, "%Y")))
p <- ggplot(ba2, aes(x=DATE,y=value,
                     col=variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(year), scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
p + scale_x_date(breaks = breaks, date_labels = "%b")
```

[image: ts using breaks]

Is there any way to get a continuous plot basically joining the lines together? using any other package or language?

Comment: I'd suggest adding a year variable, faceting on that with free x scales, and remove the spacing between facets with `theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"))`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the data frame df1 shown in the Note at the end which has a `values` column with 22 * 31 = 682 rows, one for each of the 31 dates in January for each of the 22 years from 2000 to 2021.

Then convert to ts with frequency 31 and plot.

```
tt <- ts(df1$values, start = 2000, freq = 31)
plot(tt)
```

or to use ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
z <- as.zoo(tt)
autoplot(z)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
set.seed(123)
date <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2021-12-31"), 1)
values <- seq_along(date)
df1 <- subset(data.frame(date, values), months(date) == "January")
```