# How to add years on x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

while plotting time series of one month over 20 years, I got the following plot.

```
JAN
        DATE       GPM         TRI         RCM
  1: 2001-01-01 1.5533290 1.528809632 1.553329048
  2: 2001-01-02 1.2470197 1.247874077 1.247019692
  3: 2001-01-03 0.1167777 0.115483603 0.116777682
  4: 2001-01-04 0.1590653 0.158250147 0.159065252
  5: 2001-01-05 0.1876853 0.187869975 0.187685332
 ---                                             
596: 2021-01-26 0.2822931 0.001035217 0.001007028
597: 2021-01-27 0.5613582 0.016008546 0.015868833
598: 2021-01-29 0.8848689 0.167034460 0.166523474
599: 2021-01-30 0.3361759 0.119725738 0.119348439
600: 2021-01-31 0.3453429 0.046988839 0.047117179
```

[image: plot with x axis as date]
to avoid such a plot I converted Date column to character and used ggplot to plot it.

```
dfmelt<-melt(JAN,id.vars="DATE")
dfmelt$DATE<-as.character(dfmelt$DATE)
ggplot(dfmelt,aes(x=DATE,y=value,
                  col=variable,group=1))+
  labs(title='JANUARY')+
  geom_line()
```

[image: plot with x axis as charcter]

this does give a better plot but x axis is not descriptive. How do I add years to the x axis like 2000,2002 and so on.

using the following returns the x axis without any scale points.

```
    ggplot(dfmelt,aes(x=DATE,y=value,
                  col=variable,group=1))+
  labs(title='JANUARY')+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = 2000:2021)+
  geom_line()
 

 dput(JAN[1:50])
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(11323, 11324, 11325, 11326, 
11327, 11328, 11329, 11330, 11331, 11332, 11333, 11334, 11335, 
11336, 11338, 11339, 11340, 11341, 11342, 11343, 11344, 11345, 
11346, 11347, 11348, 11349, 11350, 11351, 11352, 11353, 11688, 
11689, 11690, 11691, 11692, 11693, 11694, 11695, 11696, 11697, 
11698, 11699, 11700, 11701, 11702, 11703, 11704, 11705, 11708, 
11709), class = "Date"), GPM = c(1.5533290478978, 1.24701969168696, 
0.116777682160594, 0.159065252296044, 0.187685331871536, 0.0151661402972882, 
0.020278018811458, 0.0176270775569004, 0.0279074208473218, 0.0160315229342072, 
0.0108845983433037, 0.0138721601327613, 0.0558540236901291, 0.00906727189688938, 
0.0435902702469772, 0.0290332179873774, 0.00270738380328481, 
0.0252890188192932, 0.0229272436557711, 0.0742112864619369, 0.63188089138853, 
0.705841393296297, 0.516529939079614, 0.127323157396423, 0.0256321479421556, 
0.0323624494729457, 0.0079694189713618, 0.00376088241239789, 
0.0759068888752428, 0.138958983189343, 0.256206161642061, 0.174721437175792, 
0.230700483398665, 0.587970629156566, 0.571620125923083, 0.975451244161874, 
0.504429551956953, 0.884041147230531, 1.07488345201856, 0.180957611493698, 
0.184881578653673, 0.374001801717993, 0.362102791148718, 0.29195778339993, 
1.21737627575252, 0.338507284113606, 0.204682161851911, 0.353243602038057, 
0.396781343074674, 0.722564701254419), TRI = c(1.52880963245181, 
1.24787407735869, 0.115483602578865, 0.158250147345684, 0.187869975056161, 
0.0154199965329919, 0.0206080794846154, 0.0179152393633214, 0.0309840515964189, 
0.0164314402116303, 0.011020640632948, 0.014009522684361, 0.0560264671948149, 
0.00940288960364489, 0.0440144074914532, 0.0291591207382827, 
0.00281879608335482, 0.0258687357348923, 0.0231179141155455, 
0.0751970951048421, 0.631786069656838, 0.705468587038617, 0.515739122757699, 
0.127503088254437, 0.0261141304425291, 0.0328461160496562, 0.00801627954384064, 
0.00414500906545901, 0.0764304795934617, 0.139526285880082, 0.0242871474756638, 
0.0161267777172445, 0.0216795259687058, 0.0321224383153412, 0.190460597956337, 
0.609730049059475, 1.03156475602083, 0.766647567271779, 0.538144953702912, 
0.225904910424159, 0.0405455376019322, 0.00974115012354696, 0.770352515303129, 
1.14427766245886, 1.46214410653354, 2.17646345430129, 0.718572896408112, 
0.695926119172368, 0.464953672883994, 0.470512680102031), RCM = c(1.5533290478978, 
1.24701969168696, 0.116777682160594, 0.159065252296044, 0.187685331871536, 
0.0151661402972882, 0.020278018811458, 0.0176270775569004, 0.0279074208473218, 
0.0160315229342072, 0.0108845983433037, 0.0138721601327613, 0.0558540236901291, 
0.00906727189688938, 0.0435902702469772, 0.0290332179873774, 
0.00270738380328481, 0.0252890188192932, 0.0229272436557711, 
0.0742112864619369, 0.63188089138853, 0.705841393296297, 0.516529939079614, 
0.127323157396423, 0.0256321479421556, 0.0323624494729457, 0.0079694189713618, 
0.00376088241239789, 0.0759068888752428, 0.138958983189343, 0.0241264927288777, 
0.0159794557614494, 0.0214845385735646, 0.0316829567566502, 0.189597625286888, 
0.606003645196629, 1.04986528082511, 0.75786332559594, 0.535528758717859, 
0.224178668128073, 0.040353171152155, 0.00945945458725323, 0.769543790868592, 
1.14336633775158, 1.46421238660698, 2.18955063527956, 0.719810266439457, 
0.694317224140577, 0.46319356040037, 0.470016988791303)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001bacb52fc40>)
```

Comment: can you `dput` some data. its difficult to help when we dont have anything to work with.

Comment: I've added the first 50.

Comment: Does this `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year",date_labels = "%Y")` fix your issue?

Comment: @AltunE it does give the labels to x axis but the plot reverts back to the straight lines [the first plot].

Comment: are you only plotting January data for each year?

Comment: @AndS. YES. January per year from 2000-2021

Comment: that is why your plot looks like that. You only have data for jan in every year. How is the plot supposed to represent data in the other months if you dont have it there?

Comment: Questions seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74394802/how-to-plot-time-series-without-breaks-caused-by-missing-dates

Comment: @AndS. yes I know that. my problem is not that I have missing data. I have already worked on that issue using other method. Here my query is on changing Date to Character, how can I remove the overcrowded x axis points and introduce discrete breaks using the year variable.

Comment: To clear up your x-axis, you can convert your year-month-day variable to year-month with `dfmelt <- dfmelt %>% mutate(gooddate = floor_date(as_date(DATE), "month"))`.